# BAT file password hardcode

Tags: windows, batch-file, passwords

I have a BAT file that has the user login stored like this:

```
userid=johndoe
```

This removes the need for a user to enter the credential, they just have to answer the password.

I know it's terrible practice, but is there a way I can specify the password in a similar fashion?

Thanks

Comment: Password for what? The batch file is going to call some executable, which hopefully is smart enough to to take plaintext passwords.

Comment: It launches a stored procedure on an oracle database and creates a log.  The password is for the oracle login.  It's saying the password is wrong when it asks for it in the cmd window, but the password works fine in sql developer for example.  I figured hardcoding the password would rule out I was potentially typing it wrong.  I've tried adding password=passwordhere but it throws an error in the cmd window.

Answer (score 1):

It has been many years since I used SQL*PLUS. But I seem to remember that certain characters needed to be quoted and or escaped when they appeared in a password that is passed on the command line. I remember having a password that would work when I supplied it at the prompt, but failed when I tried to include it on the command line. Eventually I figured out how to quote/escape the password so that it worked on the command line. I think there was a similar problem with the connection string as well.

Unfortunately I can't remember exactly what triggered the problem, nor what the solution was.

Try quoting the password and/or the connection string

```
username/"passworld"@"connectionString"
```

or perhaps escaped quotes

```
username/\"password\"@\"connectionString\"
```

If the above does not work, then hopefully it is enough of a hint to help you find the right solution.